# Trying to access response data using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying something simple where I make a request from the front end of my app using the fetch API like so

```
let request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/add', {
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/json' 
    }),
    method: 'GET'
});

fetch(request).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

I am handling this request on the server like so,

```
app.get('/add', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        "number1": "2", 
        "number2": "4"
    };
    res.send(data);
});
```

However, when I try to access my data on the front end console.log(response), I get the following object

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/add", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true…}
body:(...)
bodyUsed:false
headers:Headers
ok:true
redirected:false
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:"basic"
url:"http://localhost:3000/add"
__proto__:Response
```

The response body is empty. I assumed that's where the data would show up? How do I pass data effectively from the server?

Comment: try  change `res.send(data);` to `res.end(data);`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Okay, this works on my front end

```
fetch(request).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    response.json().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The key part was the resolution of the promise chain.

Similar question here [JavaScript fetch API - Why does response.json() return a promise object (instead of JSON)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435842/javascript-fetch-api-why-does-response-json-return-a-promise-object-instead)

Answer (score 4):

Like @random_coder_101, you can also write it without nesting:

```
fetch(request)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => { console.log(data) })
  .catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```

Answer (score 2):

Could also split in to two like this

```
async fetchData() {
        let config = {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'  //or text/json
          }
        }
        fetch(http://localhost:3000/add`, config)
          .then(res => {
            return res.json();
          }).then(this.setResults);

          //setResults
          setResults(results) {
          this.details = results;

          //or: let details = results

          console.log(details)  (or: this.details)
```