# Post request is posting to database, but does not return response

Tags: json, reactjs, mongodb, rest, post

I am trying to post users who owns dogs in my database. in the registration form i handle the input when the user presses the submit button.
The user is then posted to the database. I want to use the response to attach the userId to the dog (which is a list consisting of ownerId, name, etc..).
The user is being posted to the database as far as i can see, however, this is the error that occurs:
"index.js:1446 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

if i change res.json() to res.text(), the response will be success " ".

```
  handleSubmit() {  
    let user = {}
    user.email = this.state.email
    user.password = this.state.password
    user.firstName = this.state.firstName
    user.lastName = this.state.surName
    user.dog = null;

    console.log(user);
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/rest/registration/', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: JSON.stringify(user), // data can be `string` or {object}!
        headers: new Headers({ 
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
      })

.then(res =>  res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

};

i expect the response to be what the user put into the registration form with an additional unique Id.

Comment: In regards to response how will react code help to debug the issue? did you try posting the endpoint to postman and check if there is valid response from your webservice end ?

Comment: What is the response or error ?

Comment: Postman does'nt really give any response but a 200 status

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366789/trying-to-access-response-data-using-fetch).
Here's how I would change it reflecting off of that answer.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/rest/registration/', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: JSON.stringify(user), // data can be string or {object}!
        headers: new Headers({ 
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
      })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      response.json()
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data); //Change this to what you want do show
        });
     });
```