# Usage of response in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects, fetch-api

Can someone highlight the difference between these 2 code snippets in React?

```
window.fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json().content);
})
```

and

```
window.fetch(url)
  .then((response) =>  response.json())
  .then((data) =>{
    console.log(data.content);
})
```

> response contains a Java object and content is one of the fields in
>   that object.

2nd snippet prints the correct value of content whereas 1st snippet prints undefined.

Edit: My question is not about "why response gives a Promise rather than a normal object". It is more about what are the implications of response returning a promise.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435842/javascript-fetch-api-why-does-response-json-return-a-promise-object-instead (and the many other existing Stack Overflow questions and answers where this is already explained)

Comment: As you tagged, take a look usage of fetch-api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: You can user console.log(response.data.content); in first snippet to work

Comment: @CyberAbhay in first snippet, console.log(response.data.content does not work. since a response is still a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet doesn't work because `response.json()` returns a Promise and not a simple object which is why in the second snippet it returns a correct value as you are `using .then` to get the value

```
window.fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json().content); // response.json() is not an object but a promise and hence you can't access content from it directly
})
```

The second snippet is equilvalent to

```
window.fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    response.json().then((content) => console.log(content)); 
})
```

but an be simplified to chainable promises by returning the `response.json() promise` from the first `.then` as shown in your second snippet

Answer (score 0):

This is because `response.json()` returns [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).As it returns promise, so another `then` is used to catch its response. More info about promises can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

While using javascript `fetch` you need to convert response to json using `response.json()`. You can skip extra step of converting response to json by using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) e.g.

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(res => {console.log(res)})
```

Comment: This is really irrelevant to my question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please check my edited answer