# Is there a best practice ("right way") for inspecting fetch response object in vanilla html/css/js app?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, async-await

**Background**

I cooked up a very basic (inline js in the `<script>` tag!) web app that makes a rest API request of an API I also implemented.

I'm a novice to webdev and figured that I should inspect the `response.status` but in doing so I noticed the same thing numerous other posters have: that the `fetch()` function returns either an object that contains `status` and `Header` properties with an empty `body` *or* just the response body if the `.json()` function was invoked on `response.json()`

My **question**: I wanted to use the `response.status` in a *separate piece of logic/function outside of the async function I wrapped fetch in* to action on whether or not to display an error message in some inline HTML or the parsed expected outcome. However, as you probably figured, the `response` object only contains the body if `.json()` was called, and an empty/weird Promise-y object if not.

This design to `fetch()` made wonder if my use-case for `response.status` was considered a "best practice" or is the "industry approach" to simply just evaluate the response body, and if the response body is anything other than the expected schema, then handle that as an error?

**Related secondary question**

In trying to learn more about the fetch and async function behavior, I read that chaining an invoked async function with a `.then().catch()` expression is irregular (maybe even an anti pattern?) - why would this be the case if MDN's own async docs use this syntax in their own tutorials?

link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

**More backstory**

After trawling dozens of stackoverflow posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435842/javascript-fetch-api-why-does-response-json-return-a-promise-object-instead), I realized I *could* combine the `response.json()` object and the `response.status` kvp into a new object with this code:

```
// we have to await the .json() which is a function that returns a promise
const respObj = await response.json();

//now, create and return a 'resp' object that has all desired response elements:
const resp = {
 "status":response.status,
 "body":respObj
};
return resp;
```

Comment: *returns either an object that contains...* Don't confuse the Response with the Promise that resolves to the response body representation - they're entirely separate things, and well designed code shouldn't have issues mixing up one with the other. The snippet in your question looks all right, though you could also consider having the backend integrate the status in the payload sent to the client to avoid having to do any of that.

Comment: thanks for the comment, and I agree that confusing the Response with the Promise resolving to the body is an easy altho incorrect thing to do! To your point, it's an interesting suggestion incorporating the `status` into the response body itself which would imply that it's a common practice to just inspect the body and action on that

Comment: using .then/.catch inside an async function is not necessarily an anti-pattern or bad practice - but it's rare to need to do it. When you do, you need to understand potential pitfalls. I use it

Comment: Yep, one option I like is for the body to be `{ success: false, reason: 'someReasonStringThatGetsShownToUser' }` or `{ success: true, payload: somePayload }`

Comment: *would imply that it's a common practice to just inspect the body and action on that* - not really. `response.status` and `response.ok` and `response.headers` (especially the content-type header) can all be used to determine the next step. i.e. if content-type is not application/json then you wouldn't await response.json() - because, that's likely to fail, since the server is telling you it has not sent JSON response

Comment: "*I read that chaining an invoked async function with a `.then().catch()` expression is irregular (maybe even an anti pattern?)*" - no it isn't. Where did you get that from? Sure, `await` is often simpler than `.then()` if you can use it, but there's nothing wrong with the latter.

Comment: @Bergi I read it in a few remarks/answers to other threads on stackoverflow, and a fullstack swe buddy said it gave "him anti-pattern vibes" altho he fully conceded he was far more fluent in react specific approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access to elements of the response besides just the parsed JSON, then by all means, you can create your own function that calls `fetch()` and uses some logic and then returns multiple pieces of the response data.  I would personally probably not repackage the `response` data structure, but rather just leave it intact so the caller can get anything they want from there including headers, etc...

Here's an example:

```
async function fetchJSON(...args) {
    const response = await fetch(...args);
    // check for non 2xx status
    if (!response.ok) {
         throw new Error(`Response status ${response.status}`, { cause: response });
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return { data, response };
}
```

This function returns a promise that resolves to an object that contains both the parsed JSON data and the original response object.  This allows the caller to check on anything they want to in the original response object.

If `response.ok` is not true, then it will reject with an error object that also contains the original response object.

> My question: I wanted to use the response.status in a separate piece of logic/function outside of the async function I wrapped fetch in to action on whether or not to display an error message in some inline HTML or the parsed expected outcome. However, as you probably figured, the response object only contains the body if .json() was called, and an empty/weird Promise-y object if not.

That's not really the right way to think of it.  Both `fetch()` and `response.json()` return promises.  The promise that `fetch()` returns will resolve to the `response` object.  The promise that `response.json()` returns will resolve to the parsed JSON data object.  If you use `await` with each of these, then you can use the promise to just directly get the resolved result (as shown in my example above).

> This design to fetch() made wonder if my use-case for response.status was considered a "best practice" or is the "industry approach" to simply just evaluate the response body, and if the response body is anything other than the expected schema, then handle that as an error?

It is common to check `response.ok` because a 4xx or 5xx status does not reject the promise from `fetch()`.  If you're specifically looking for a 3xx error, then you may write specific code to check for that.  `response.ok` will tell you if it is a 2xx status (usually what you want when requesting data).  You can skip this check and "assume" that downstream when you try to read/parse the JSON, you will get an error if there was no JSON (and this is the case, but it will likely be a JSON parse error, not an indication of the real problem that it wasn't a 2xx status that returned the desired data.  So I find it better to specifically check `response.ok` so I know I'm only trying to parse JSON if the request was deemed successful (from my point of view).

You will find that third party browser libraries that offer a bit more convenient interface such as `axios()` don't even make you handle two separate steps in the process.  You just make a request and they return data or an error.  That's what my small `fetchJSON()` function above does too.  It handles the internal checks itself.  If the response doesn't contain JSON or contains invalid JSON, it will reject and your code can check the resulting error object to see why it rejected.

> In trying to learn more about the fetch and async function behavior, I read that chaining an invoked async function with a .then().catch() expression is irregular (maybe even an anti pattern?) - why would this be the case if MDN's own async docs use this syntax in their own tutorials?

So, you generally don't want to mix lots of `async/await` and `.then()` and `.catch()` within the same function as the flow of control can get confusing to follow.  If you mark the function `async`, then inside it you're probably using `await` instead of `.then()` because the whole point of an `async` function is to enable the simpler flow of control by using `await`.  There are occasional cases where I find a `.catch()` to be simpler and less code that a `try/catch` around an `await` when I want to handle the error locally, but that's not a very common case for me.

I wouldn't go so far to call it an anti-pattern to occasionally find a situation where `.catch()` is simpler than `try/catch` around an `await`, but that's really just personal preference.  But, I would call it an anti-pattern to be freely mixing `await` and `.then()` all over an `async` function.  That just makes the code more complicated to follow.  In general, you want to pick one style or the other for your code within a given function.